# what is the difference between eq("+index+") and eq(index) in jQuery

Tags: jquery

In an example where eq() function is used, it was used as  eq("+index+")

I haven't seen syntax like this before. What does "+" sign on both sides mean? How is it different from eq(index)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jQuery, `eq` refers to two slightly different things: [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), the function, and [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), the selector.

The function version is chained onto a jQuery object, so you'd see examples like:

```
$(".whatever").eq(index)
```

Whereas the other form is used as part of the selector string, so you'll see people concatenate the index with the rest of the string:

```
$(".whatever:eq(" + index + ")")
```

For performance reasons (and better readability in many cases), the jQuery documentation recommends the first form, the `.eq` function.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using eq as a function you should use it like

```
$("div").eq(3).html("test");
```

if as a selector:

```
var index = 3;
$("div:eq(" + index + ")").html("test");
```

2 ways, same result....

Answer (score 1):

Probably you were looking at an example similar to this:

```
$("foo:eq(" + index + ")")
```

You are probably comparing that to something like this:

```
$("foo").eq(index)
```

The difference is that the former is a (faux) CSS selector syntax and the latter is just a method call. Compare http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/ to http://api.jquery.com/eq/.

Comment: Thank you very much to all! The answers are very helpful and informative and fully clarified the issue for me!